# Mercadopago checkout pro, Algo salio mal

Tags: mercadopago, aplicación-movil, checkout

Estoy teniendo un problema hace un tiempo y es que al realizar los pagos desde el movil no importa si es android o ios, si el usuario tiene la aplicacion de MP, abre dicha app el problema es que al ingresar el PIN e ingresar sale el mensaje de "Algo salio mal".
En desktop o si el usuario no tiene instalado la app en el movil funciona de 10.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.